# Failed to scan [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/] from classloader hierarchy

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kubernetes, jar

Trying to deploy my web app through Kubernetes cluster and I receive this error that prevents my pod from running. It fails with a BackOff error. When I run 'kubectl logs pod xxx' to try and understand more about the pod, this is what populates:

```
2022-06-28 04:12:44.198  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.b.webconsole.WebconsoleApplication     : Starting WebconsoleApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on webapp-deployment-66c555cd6b-8svtv with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2022-06-28 04:12:44.200  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.b.webconsole.WebconsoleApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-06-28 04:12:44.682  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-28 04:12:44.722  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-06-28 04:12:45.195  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): xxxx (https)
2022-06-28 04:12:45.221  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-28 04:12:45.221  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2022-06-28 04:12:45.271  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/] from classloader hierarchy
```

This sets off a bunch of IOExceptions in which IntelliJ is unable to open the root Jar file(s) for:

- spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar

etc. So I'm wondering why this is happening?

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.blackbook</groupId>
    <artifactId>webconsole</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webconsole</name>
    <description>Web console for EMM guide BlackBook</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>18.0.1.1</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Android Management API dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-androidmanagement</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20200221-1.30.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Google Play EMM API dependency for AdminWebToken-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-androidenterprise</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20200801-1.30.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- When making changes, server will automatically perform the restart -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.10</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# For Java 18,
FROM openjdk:18
COPY target/webconsole-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE xxxx
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Not sure if my version of Java is the issue, wondering if anyone has run into this using openjdk18?

Comment: Just updated Tomcat to a later version, thought that would help resolve dependency to open Jar files: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
   <version>10.1.0-M16</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was target a lower jdk!

Comment: Can you specify which JDK you targeted? That will help future readers understand the solution better, while also determining if the solution is even relevant to them.